# Wampp with xdebug3 and VScode, no connection

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug-3

I've made a setup with Wampp to be able switching PHP versions easily.
My issue is the debuggung. it was working fine with Xampp, Xdebug3 and VScode.
Under Wampp I'm getting no connection when vscode is listening for Xdebug. The ports match, the setting and PHPInfo says 9003. I've added the php version folder to path, no change. Xdebug is setup in the PHP ini and rteflected in the PHPInfo.
Any idea wehat is missing?

Comment: dump your phpinfo into the xdebug wizard https://xdebug.org/wizard and check that it says that it is already installed. if it suggests a version to install, then it is not installed correctly

Answer (score 0):

Thank you JoSSte,
I've used the wizard and followed the instructions. It works now.

Comment: Please insert more information on your answer, explain how did you get to the solution and what you want to achieve.

Comment: After paste phpinfo into the xdebug wizard, there are instructions what kind of file need to be added and may renamed. In Wampp you have to do those changes in the PHP version you'd like to use. And then I restarted the computer and it did the trick. I could listen in VScode to xdebug and debug my application that way. I hope this clarifies it better.